# Trying to get up & running with a Protobuf & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get up and running with JavaScript & Protobuf. I cloned this repository (https://github.com/nyrobert/js-protobuf-example), which provides a simple example in JavaScript.  It provides a simple `Person` schema.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Person {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string email = 3;

    enum PhoneType {
        HOME = 0;
        WORK = 1;
    }

    message PhoneNumber {
        string number = 1;
        PhoneType type = 2;
    }

    repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}
```

I then compiled the schema with

```sh
$ protoc \
    --proto_path=protocol_buffers/definitions \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:protocol_buffers/messages \
    protocol_buffers/definitions/person.proto
```

And tried to run

```js
'use strict';

var message = require('./protocol_buffers/messages/person_pb');

var person = new message.Person();
person.setId(1);
person.setName('John Doe');
person.setEmail('john.doe@gmail.com');
```

but encountered

```
$ node index.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      master
.../js-protobuf-example/protocol_buffers/messages/person_pb.js:402
  return jspb.Message.setProto3IntField(this, 1, value);
                      ^

TypeError: jspb.Message.setProto3IntField is not a function
    at proto.Person.setId (.../js-protobuf-example/protocol_buffers/messages/person_pb.js:402:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../js-protobuf-example/index.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Any idea what's going on here? My version of Node is 14.15.4. And my version of Protobuf is

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "google-protobuf": "^3.4.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `google-protobuf` version in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "google-protobuf": "3.15.8"
}
```